# How to reverse geocoding

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a web project and it that i know how to display google map using coordinates as follows

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?
      center=15.999989,80.000099&zoom=14&size=600x600&sensor=true" />
```

but how i can perform reverse geocoding to get the location of that coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Let me google that for you: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

You make a JavaScript request to the following URL: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true_or_false` and you will receive a JSON resonse with a list of possible locations. You then look through that list and decide wich of the locations is the one that you need (maybe you need the exact address with street number, but maybe in other cases the city's name will suffice).